# Minikube 0.5.0 : cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.101 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: kubernetes, x509certificate

starting today with a brand new install of Minikube 0.5.0 and Kubectl 1.3.0 (my machine is running ubuntu 14.04 64 bits).

Just start Minikube with minikube start and everything seems to run fine (Vbox machine is created and started) but contacting the cluster seems impossible due to certificate issue:

```
laurent@ponyo:~$kubectl cluster-info
Unable to connect to the server: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.99.101 because it doesn't contain any IP SAN
```

kubectl config view runs fine and outputs the following config

```
laurent@ponoy:~$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/laurent/.minikube/apiserver.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.101:443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
 user:
   client-certificate: /home/laurent/.minikube/apiserver.crt
   client-key: /home/laurent/.minikube/apiserver.key
```

Any clue on this issue ? Is there any extra step before starting minikube regarding cert provisionning ? Is there any pointer on how to solve that ?

Thank you for help,

Comment: Hey, I think you posed this corresponding github issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/286

Would you mind including the output of that command there?

Comment: Sure ! Didn't know if was really an issue so asked help here too...

Comment: As suggested, I ran
`openssl x509 -in ~/.minikube/apiserver.crt -text` and certificats were all fine.
I have pursued investigations and found that I have some trouble with my corporate proxy. When unsetting all env vars (lowercase and uppercase), I am now able to run kubectl commands. However, when proxy is disabled before launching minikube startup, kubernetes has trouble starting/syncing the kubernetes-dashboard pod...

So for now, I have to 2 deal with 2 terminals: one having proxy settings and start/stopping minikube, one having no proxy settings and issuing kubectl commands.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the proxy issue. We'll look into fixing that in minikube.

Answer (score 0):

You can now pass in env vars into the minikube VM (such as HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY)

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#using-minikube-with-an-http-proxy